# How to select nested properties in JavaBean with JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using iReport/Jaspersoft Studio to design a `jrxml` template.

My source bean is as follows:

```
public class Person {
   private List<Phone> phones;
}

public class Phone {
  private String type; //home, business, private...
  private String number;
}
```

Problem: how can I show all phone numbers repeatedly in my template, but only those who have `type = "home"` defined?

This is what I did:
- added a DataAdapter that returns a dummy collection of `Person`s.
- Dataset Query Dialog > Java Bean > add `phone` field of class `Person` as jasper field (`type java.util.List`).

So far so good, but I now only have a field of type list in my jasper parameters.

How can I now acutally show the ´phone.number` attribute repeatedly?

Comment: Maybe you need a subreport.  https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports

Comment: So are you saying for every `List` element in my complex object I'd need a subreport (means: explicit single jrxml file)? What would mean I have to nest all the reports accordingly to all the list?

Comment: To represent the object Person you need one main jrxml. The "detail band " of main jrxml will represent one Person. 
A person have a list of phone, to represent a phone you need another jrxml file.
The second jrxml will be inside the detail band of the mail jrxml like any other element of Person

Comment: Ok so I'll need one jrxml file per java class.

Comment: It's not a rule, but in your case is true.